# get information from a variable inside a private method from other private method in SpringBoot Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

Holla developers .....i'm trying to access a variable already  declared and filled in one framed method from other one , in this BattleShip project im doing using Java as BackEnd and Vuejs as Front....here my first method;

```
 private List<Set<String>>makeShipsSinkHitsDto(Set<Salvo> salvoSet, GamePlayer gamePlayer){
        List<Set<String>>dto=new LinkedList<>();
        Set<String> sunkShips=new HashSet<>();--->THIS IS THE VARIABLE I WANT TO ACCESS FROM OTHER METHOD

        for(Ship ship:getOppDetails(gamePlayer).getShips()){
            Integer shipSize=ship.getShipPositions().size();
            for(Salvo salvo:salvoSet.stream().collect(Collectors.toList())){
                for( String LocationShots:ship.getShipPositions()){
                    if(salvo.getShootToPositions().contains(LocationShots)){
                        shipSize=shipSize-1;
                        if(shipSize==0){
                            sunkShips.add(ship.getTypeShip());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        dto.add(sunkShips);
        return dto;
    }
```

where the variable :

```
Set<String> sunkShips=new HashSet<>()
```

would be the one to storage all the sunk ships , then in a second method im evolving, i would like to access this variable in order to set a logic of the Game Over state, but can't find a not so complicated way of doing it!!
here my second not yet finished method :

```
private Map<String,Object> makeGetStateOfGamePlayerDto(GamePlayer gamePlayer){
        Map<String,Object>dto=new HashMap<>();
        if(getOppDetails(gamePlayer)==null){
            dto.put("state","Waiting for opponent in game");
        }
        else if(getOppDetails(gamePlayer)!=null){
            dto.put("state","Welcome to game,place Ships please");
            if(gamePlayer.getShips().size()==5){
                dto.put("state","Ships in Coordenates, Shoot!!!");
            }
            if(gamePlayer.salvos.size()<getOppDetails(gamePlayer).salvos.size()){
                dto.put("state","Enemy hasn't shot, wait for their shots");
            }
                    AND THEN HERE SOME CONDITIONAL ALLOWING ME TO ACCESS
                    THAT VARIABLE IN THE FIRST METHOD ...!
        }

        return dto;

    }
```

Any advice please?....thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: You cannot access method scoped variables outside of the method itself. Pass it into the method as an argument if you really must.

Comment: any explicit example please?

Answer (score 0):

You could either pass the Variable that you want to store the sunk ships in to the method, or what in my opinion would be much cleaner, return the variable. If your method already has to return another type, try to refactor it in order to separate concerns. If you really need a shared variable, then create it from the outside and pass it to the areas where you need it, but be aware to think of thread safety and not running in to any race conditions, when accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access variables declared in a method from outside, no matter if the method is private, public, etc.

What you need to do in your case is to store the variable in your main logic (or from wherever you call your two functions) and pass it to the functions that need it as an argument.

If you need more specific help, we gotta know where your functions are called from.